# open excel and take screenshot using python selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I am automating some browser testing using selenium and python.The script opens the application via chrome browser,enters the userid and password and traverses through the web browser application.I am taking screenshots of every page which is seen while traversing.However i am stuck at one place.The application at one place when clicked downloads a excel file.The excel gets downloaded at downloads folder.My requirement is now to open the excel file and take screenshot of the excel file and then again go back to web browser and keep traversing.

Comment: So? What have you done for this? Show us what you have done, and what problem you're facing?

Comment: As others have pointed out, Selenium gives you the ability to interact with the browser only.  You will need to use another tool to interact with the system under test to grab a screenshot of excel, and I see a few answers below that may help.  You may consider discussing the requirements of the test.  Do they want to know that Excel has been started and opened the correct file?  If the requirement is to verify the content of the excel file, you can use Python to interact with the file directly, without having to check that it's opening or grabbing a screenshot.

Comment: This has nothing to do with [selenium] or [google-chrome] tags, please remove those tags and add other tags that are relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

@Rahul Mukerjee

After opening excel file,use this code to take screen shot:

```
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con, win32api
hwin = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
width = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)
height = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)
left = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN)
top = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN)
hwindc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwin)
srcdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwindc)
memdc = srcdc.CreateCompatibleDC()
bitmap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcdc, width, height)
memdc.SelectObject(bitmap)
memdc.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), srcdc, (left, top), win32con.SRCCOPY)
bitmap.SaveBitmapFile(memdc, 'C:\\screenshot.bmp')
```

"C:\screenshot.bmp" :It is the location where you want to save the screen grab.
Only windows compatible.

Got from a solution in stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Which platform are you working on? You could try opening the file with python then use this module to do a screen grab: https://wiki.wxpython.org/WorkingWithImages#A_Flexible_Screen_Capture_App.

Since you wouldn't be opening the excel sheet in the browser I don't think this would be a task for selenium.

Comment: I am using windows 10

Answer (score -1):

```
So the solution in my view can be:

1.You know in which location the file gets downloaded.So you can hard code the location of file in your script.If the name of excel is same everytime it is downloaded then it is good,otherwise you need to capture the name of file and store it.
2.You can continue on running your tests after downloading the file.
3.Now you can take the screen shot of the downloaded file once you are finished traversing all the pages.

Hope this helps.
```

Comment: Can you consider adding some code block to support your verbatim? Thanks

Comment: Thanks all.I am using windows 10.@Rakesh.i need to open the file and take screenshot.?I can open the file with os.startfile('C:\\Users\\Rahul Mukherjee\\Downloads\\file.xls') but how to take screenshot of the opened file and saving its output?

Comment: Definitely..

@Rahul:Can you share the website which you are using?

Comment: you open a file with command os.startfile('C:\\Users\\Rahul Mukherjee\\Downloads\\file.xls') now i can see its opened .how to take its screenshot and save into a file.I am not opening in browser ,so driver.save_screenshot('people_link_NJ_7.png') is not working.Please help

Comment: @Rakesh i cannot share  website as this is internal to my organization and it will not open from outside.My question is just how to take a screenshot of a file opened."you open a file with command os.startfile('C:\\Users\\Rahul Mukherjee\\Downloads\\file.xls') now i can see its opened .how to take its screenshot and save into a file.I am not opening in browser ,so driver.save_screenshot('people_link_NJ_7.png') is not working.Please help"

Comment: Why are you posting two answers to the same question? Is there some reason the two shouldn't be combined?

Comment: Haven't posted two answers.One was the approach and other code.But by mistake posted it as different answer.

Comment: Thanks all i am able to resolve the issue with pyscreenshot. import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import os
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # fullscreen 
    os.startfile('C:\\Users\\Rahul Mukherjee\\file.xls')
    time.sleep(3)
    im=ImageGrab.grab()
    im.show()
    im.save('C:\\screenshots\\file.png')